# T-SQL average calculation

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, average, moving-average

I want to incorporate two average calculations for a bunch of value columns in my select statement.

see this link for my simplified table structure including the desired output calculation: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/v5E1xAKF)

**1) moving average:**

Month1 = value of the value1-column for that month, Month2 = if sum == 0 then write 0, else avg(Month1 and Month2) and so on.

So for each product, I want the moving average for each month within one year.
I have this set up in my Excel but I can't transfer the expression to sql.

**2) overall average:**

for each product, calculate the average over all years and duplicate the calculated value to all rows for that product.

I hope you can help me out with this. It looks like I need a procedure but maybe it is just a simple statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL-Server 2012 supports the [analytic functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) required to do this:

```
SELECT  Product,
        Month,
        Year,
        Value,
        AVG_YTD = AVG(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY Year ORDER BY Month),
        AVG_Year = AVG(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY Product, Year),
        AVG_Overall = AVG(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY Product)
FROM    T;
```

**[Simplified Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d51a2/2)**